# wordpress permalink getting the previous clicked link

Tags: php, wordpress

I have displayed the title from the selected category. And it's an anchor tag, but The permalink is not working. What is the problem here? it's get the old link that might somewhere just clicked . But not working with the exact category.

```
        <a class="heading-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">           
         <?php

            query_posts('cat=4&showposts=1');

         if (have_posts()) : 
           while (have_posts()) : the_post();

         the_title();

         endwhile;
        endif;

        wp_reset_query();

             ?>    
   </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

place `<a>` tag inside your loop

```
<?php

        query_posts('cat=4&showposts=1');

     if (have_posts()) : 
       while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

    <?php  endwhile;
    endif;

    wp_reset_query();

         ?>
```